# Language & Region all options dispear

Tags: language

[image: all setting dispear]

recently updates make this. (don't know which day it happend). click on + - nothing happen.

did anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you press Unlock and put your password, then the + sign works and you can add a language. After that you will see everything.