# Language and Region section is empty

Tags: release-loki

I'm using 0.4.1 Loki, most of functions are working fine but
Language and Region in Settings, contents are all empty.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: press on the lock and put your password. then you should be able to change the settings

Comment: It is most likely a duplicate of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/language-region-all-options-dispear

Comment: Thank you for help, now I understand how it works, and I will checkout more topics before I post my problem from next time.